# Count instances of text string and replace with number

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to find ways to speed up adding footnotes to a Google slides document. What I want is a script that looks for every instance of a text string throughout the document (say ‘*’) and then replaces each instance of that string with the number corresponding to that instance e.g. the first * gets replaced with 1, second * gets replaced with 2, and so on. I realise this method can only be used once but this would still save me a lot of time. Is there an easy way to do this? I can’t work out how to replace with a variable but it seems like it should be possible.

Comment: There is a way but it is not easy. 
You need a script that needs to browse through all the slides, then inside each slide through all page elements. Depending on the page element type (some of them cannot contain text, so you must skip them), the script would search for text and replace it with the running number.
If you have multiple text you want to replace, you'd need to keep a dictionary of { [text:string}:running_number}

Comment: I have code that reads elements on slides and pulls text. Its function is to create a table of contents. It pulls the page elements in the order they were added and looks for text. It stops when text is found. You would want to keep going but it would be a start.  https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1X_zyari_BpEWjJAqnOLrb6rWQvZBvR2wNoBgg5WrgIs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we have this slide below as our sample data.

#### Sample Data:

[image: sample1]
[image: sample2]

If we want to replace all occurrences of a string (e.g. "replace"), then we will need to traverse all `shapes` of each `slides` and replace its occurrences with the counter.

#### Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();
  var counter = 0;
  // traverse each slide
  slides.forEach(function (slide) {
    var shapes = slide.getShapes();
    // traverse each shape
    shapes.forEach(function (shape) {
      // get its text content
      var text = shape.getText()
      var string = text.asString();
      // replace all occurrences of string (e.g. "replace")
      // by an incrementing number
      string = string.replace(/replace/g, function() {
        return ++counter;
      });
      // set the shape's text
      text.setText(string);
    });
  });
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output1]
[image: output2]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a ready solution. Rather the way to solve the task.

You can download all texts of your presentation as a TXT file:

[image]

Then you can process this text with JS script. Something like this:

```js
// your text with markers (#)
var txt = `
doleste # atus etur, consequi odi quos alit audipsunt as is est# ant.

consequi # odi quos alit audipsunt es vere ipsam aut am

doluptae et que nonse # um volupta aped ulloreictat as is est ant.
`;

// get every marker + several characters before and after
var find_for = txt.match(/...#.../g);

console.log(find_for); // Output: [ 'te # at', 'est# an', 'ui # od', 'se # um' ]

// replace marker with numbers 1, 2, 3...
var replace_with = find_for.map((m,i) => m.replace(/#/, i+1));

console.log(replace_with); // Output: [ 'te 1 at', 'est2 an', 'ui 3 od', 'se 4 um' ]
```

This way you will get two arrays: `find_for` and `replace_with`.

Then you will need a script to perform the text replaces.

```
'te # at' --> 'te 1 at'
'est# an' --> 'est2 an'
'ui # od' --> 'ui 3 od'
'se # um' --> 'se 4 um'
```

Which is, I believe, a quite trivial task.

But there can be errors if some markets has the same neighbor characters. Probably you need to take four or five neighbor characters with markers: `....#....` or asymetric `......#..`. It's up to you.